# Changing the SharePoint Timeline date fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, timeline

I have a SharePoint Online site that has a task list with the Timeline enabled.  However, the start/due dates are only used for past or present tasks.  For future tasks, I have a "Planned Start Date" and "Planned Due Date" field instead.  (This was to satisfy another client requirement.)

However, I need my timeline to use the planned dates rather than the built-in start and end dates.  How can I customize my timeline to use those fields instead of the default ones?

Comment: So, the client requirement will include making a separate copy of the event once it is no longer "planned" with an actual start date?

Comment: No, the built-in Start Date and Due Date fields are for the actual task dates.  However, they'd like the timeline to show the Planned Start and Planned End dates instead.

Comment: And then switch to the actual when the project starts?

Comment: I wound up creating two sets of fields, Planned Start/End and Actual Start/End.  Then I created a workflow to copy Actual (or if blank, Planned) into the real Start Date and Due Date fields.  It works like a charm!

Comment: rhymeswithmogul  I'd recommend posting your own answer